# How to find document frequency in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I need help with this problem to create a program in R that find:
-The minimum number of documents that indexer handles is 4.
-Extract all terms from each document to build matrix contains the term frequency in each document (to be printed).
-print each term and it's DF (document frequency)

I tried to enter files by for loop and the function but didn't work and i don't know how to solve this

```
analyze <- function(filename) {
    # Plots the average, min, and max inflammation over time.
    # Input is character string of a csv file.
    dat <- read.csv(file = filename, header = FALSE)
    avg_day_inflammation <- apply(dat, 2, mean)
    plot(avg_day_inflammation)
    max_day_inflammation <- apply(dat, 2, max)
    plot(max_day_inflammation)
    min_day_inflammation <- apply(dat, 2, min)
    plot(min_day_inflammation)
  }

  analyze("E://FCI-H//level 3 - Second Semester//Information Retrival//Section//assignment//assignment3//1.csv")
```

this code shows me an error but I expect to solve this by open more than 5 files and combine them then make a matrix and find document frequency

Comment: This is clearly a uni exercise. As such I'll leave a few tips here, and one comment. Comment: Please format your questions properly. It is not clear from your question what you are answering. For example add the error to your question if this is what you want help with. Tips: (tip 1) Try looking at `?colMeans`, and (tip 2) try `read.csv(file.choose())` to see if you can open the file manually. (tip 3) if you want to print something try the `print` function, rather than visualizing with a plot.

Answer (score 0):

> this is the solution of my problem

```
library(tm)

mypath = "E://FCI-H//level 3 - Second Semester//Information Retrival//Section//assignment//assignment3" setwd(mypath)


txt_files_ls = list.files(path=mypath, pattern="*.txt")  txt_files_df <- lapply(txt_files_ls, function(x) {read.table(file = x, header = F, sep ="/")})

combined_df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(txt_files_df, as.data.frame))

names(combined_df) <- "text" myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(combined_df$text))

tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus,control = list(removePunctuation = TRUE, stopwords = TRUE)) dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus, control = list(weighting = function(x) weightTfIdf(x, normalize = FALSE), stopwords = TRUE))

inspect(tdm) inspect(dtm)
```